Finding Deboo's integrator time constant and transfer function
I tried to determine the transfer function and time constant of Deboo's non-inverting integrator. If I calculate with an ideal op-amp, then my calculation fails if the ratio of R2/R1 and R4/R3 is the same (zero in the denominator.) Did I miscalculate something? Algebra is not my friend. What could be the problem?
You can see my calculations below:



EDIT:
I calculated not neglecting Aol. The time constant looks good, but the K doesn't. What could be the problem?

EDIT2:
Thanks for the very helpful comments. However, I would like to understand exactly how it works in the frequency range, because I want to use it as a dc-servo.
I also analyzed the traditional non-inverting integrator, similarly to the previous one.
I did not neglect Aol in my calculations. Calculating with Aol creates a pole in the denominator.


For example, let each resistor be 1K and the capacitor be 10nF.
The generated pole: w = 1/[RC(1+A)] [rad/s]
Its frequency is: f = w/2pi [Hz]
I choose the LT1002 as an example op-amp. According to LTSpice, the open-loop gain of this is ~ 118dB.
Thus A[db] ~ 118dB, from which A = 10^(118/20) = 794328 (Very high gain)
According to my formula, the pole is: ~ 0.02Hz.
I also got this result when simulating in LTSpibe.

Back to deboo's integrator...
I also simulated this. According to the simulation, the pole is ~ 82mHz.

Unfortunately, this does not work out with my formula. The results of the formula will be:
T = 5.0025us
w = 199900 rad/s
f = 31815 Hz
What is interesting is that if I calculate with the plain T = RC/2, this frequency is also obtained.
More precisely:
w = 200000 rad/s
f = 31831Hz
The difference is caused by Aol, but it is minimal.
What is also interesting is that my formula calculates the value of K well.
K[dB] = 112dB comes out, which corresponds to the simulated result.
Question:
How could the pole in the simulation be calculated?

I updated the formulas.

you are asking for the pole of the real integrator function.  Assuming an open-loop gain of Aol=1E6 the pole frequency is app. wp=(2/RC)/Aol=0.2 rad/s,
This is equivalent to fp=32mHz. Of curse, this assumes that all passive parts have no tolerances.

If Aol = 794328, R = 1k, and C = 10 nF, the pole is ~ 0.2518 rad/s. The frequency is ~ 40mH.
According to the simulation, it is 82mH, what is the reason for the discrepancy? Why can't I calculate exactly? However, I was able to calculate the traditional non-inverting integrator exactly. Thanks for the help.

you should not overestimate this "discrepency". The simulation model for the opamp contains some additional parameters which do not appear in our handmade calculations (e.g. finite input and output impedances). In addition, in reality Aol is a frequency dependent gain. How did you find the value of Aol=794328?

I measured the open-loop gain of the LT1002 in LTSpice. Aol ~ 118dB. From this, A = 10^(118/20).
Of course, I know that it depends on the frequency, but its poles are at a very high frequency, it cannot have an effect.
I examined the effect of the output impedance and the CM, DM impedances, there is no effect for the integrator pole, only Aol.
I also performed the simulation and calculations on the traditional non-inverting integrator, the calculated and simulated results are the same.

@slimcold - please see my EDIT 2 for the pole frequency.

Thank you for your help! completely understandable. I'm still a student at university, I have a lot to learn. :) I would like to use an integrator as a DC servo. I want to determine the transfer function of a non-inverting circuit with a DC servo. Can I solve it with the KCL method I'm using?

Of course, KCL works always - however, in many cases it is advisable not to start at the very beginning (with KCL). Why not use known results - for example Acl=(1+Ra/Rb) for a non-inv. opamp or (as I did) Acl=Hf/Hr.

I would have used KCL to calculate, but it didn't work, why did I calculate incorrectly? Or did I not use the method well? I calculated on a similar principle as here: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa024b/sloa024b.pdf?ts=1718289015425&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Quote: ".... it didn't work, why did I calculate incorrectly? Or did I not use the method well?" How could I know? I must admit that I have not enough time to follow in detail your calculation....sorry.

IMPORTANT - slimcolt, there is something I forgot to mention up tp now: The Deboo integrator is EXTREMLY sensitive to parts mismatch. Example: All resistors 1k, except R1=0.95k. The Bode diagram will drastically change and the maximum gaian at low frequency will much lower (and the pole frequency much larger).

Realizing that the principle function of this integrator is based on the de-damping properties of a Negative-Impedance Converter (NIC), the calculation of the integrators transfer function ist straight-forward:
1.) Lets start with the input impedance of the NiC at the non-inv. opamps input (your notation, opamp ideal):
\$I_3 = \frac{U_o-U_p}{R_2}\$ with \$U_p = U_n = U_o\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_4}\$
Therefore:
\$r_{in} = \frac{U_p}{-I_3} = -R_3\frac{R_2}{R_4}\$ and \$r_{in}=-R_3\$ (for Conversion factor k=R2/R4=1)
2.) Next step: Applying the Voltage division rule
\$\frac{U_p}{U_i} = \frac{(Z_c || r_{in})}{(Z_c || r_{in})+R_1} = \dots= \frac{1}{1+R_1(sC+\frac{1}{R_{in}})}\$
For selecting \$R_1 = -r_{in} = R_3\$ we get:
\$\frac{Up}{Ui}=\frac{1}{s\tau}\$ with \$\tau = R_1C\$
3.) Because the opamp output voltage is \$U_o = U_p(1+\frac{R_2}{R_4}) = 2U_p\$ (for R2=R4) we get the integrators transfer function
\$\frac{U_o}{U_i}=\frac{2U_p}{U_i} = \frac{2}{s\tau}\$ with \$\tau = R_1C\$

EDIT 1 :
Alternative derivation of the transfer function:
From feedback theory we know that
\$H(s)=Aol \frac{H_f}{(1+A_{ol} H_r)}\$  with return function \$H_r\$ and forward damping \$H_f\$.
Therefore, with Aol approaching infinity and
\$H_r=\frac{R_3}{R_3+R_4} - \frac{(R_1 || Z_c)}{(R_1 || Z_c) + R_2}\$
and
\$H_f=\frac{(R_2 || Z_c)}{(R_2 || Z_c) + R_1}\$
we directly arrive (setting R1=R2=R3=R4=R) at
\$H(s)=\frac{H_f}{H_r} = \frac{2}{sRC}\$
======================
EDIT 2: Pole frequency for the real opamp.
When we are using the transfer function (see above)
H(s)=AoHf/(1+HrAo)
without setting Ao to infinity, we finally arrive at a first-order lowpass function (for 4 equal resistors R) - written in the classical form:
H(s)=(Aol/2)/[1+sRC(0.5 + Aol/4)].
With R=1k and C=10nF and Aol=795000 the 3-db (angular) cutoff frequency (identical to the pole angular frequency) is app
wo=1/T=0.5 rad/sec with T=RC(0.5 + Aol/4).
From this: fo=79.6 mHz and closed-loop gain Acl(f=0)=Aol/2
Both values (fo and Acl) are very close to the simulated values.

Thanks for the answer, very useful! Then, according to them, it should be investigated in the time domain, not in the frequency domain.
I simulated a circuit in LTSpice (AC Analysis). For simplicity, each resistor has a value of 1K. Thus, according to your formula, the time constant is T = 1K*10nF=10uS
w=1/T = 100000 rad/s, from which f= w/2pi =15915.5Hz
According to the simulation, f=40Hz and K[dB] = 57.6dB If I simulate with an AD8038 OP-AMP.
As I change the OP-AMP, different values ​​always appear.

@slimcolt Please consider the factor "2" in the numerator of the transfer function. Therefore we have H(s)=2/sT=1/0.5sT and the effective integrator time constant is To=T/2=1/(R1*C/2).

Thank you for letting me know. Unfortunately I forgot.

@slimcolt if you are interested in an alternative way for finding the transfer function, please the EDIT in my answer.
